# How to convert feet and inches to inches in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Basically, I was told that if I wanted to get better at programming, I should pick a projeect and stick to it. I chose to write a BMI calculator. Here's the code.

```
def get_values()
    puts("Please enter your height in metres.")
    height = gets.to_f
    puts("Please enter your weight in kilograms.")
    weight = gets.to_f
    bmi = ((weight) / (height * height))
    puts("Your BMI is: " + bmi.to_s)
    if (bmi < 18.5)
        puts("You are underweight.")
    elsif (bmi > 18.5) and (bmi < 25.0)
        puts("You are a healthy weight.")
    elsif (bmi > 25) and (bmi < 30)
        puts("You are overweight.")
    elsif (bmi > 30)
        puts("You are obese.")
    end
end

  def get_values_imperial()
    puts("Please enter your height in inches.")
    height = gets.to_f
    puts("Please enter your weight in pounds.")
    weight = gets.to_f
    bmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
    puts("Your BMI is: " + bmi.to_s)
    if (bmi < 18.5)
        puts("You are underweight.")
    elsif (bmi > 18.5) and (bmi < 25.0)
        puts("You are a healthy weight.")
    elsif (bmi > 25) and (bmi < 30)
        puts("You are overweight.")
    elsif (bmi > 30)
        puts("You are obese.")
    end
end
 
  def main()
    puts("Welcome to the BMI calculator. Would you like to continue with metric or imperial values?")
    answer = gets.chomp
    if (answer == "metric") or (answer == "Metric")
      get_values()
    elsif (answer == "imperial") or (answer == "Imperial")
        get_values_imperial()
    else
      ("Unsupported unit of measurement.")
    end
  end
  
  main()
```

Basically, the issue is this: most people don't know thir height in inches, or so I would assume. I'd like the user to be able to enter a height, eg. 6'1", in feet and inches. Is this posssible without using the Numeric class?

Comment: Convert feet to inches, then add the remainder inches. Internally, store everything in inches.

Comment: There are 13 instances of the `Numeric` class and 19 calls to methods of those objects in your code already. So, given that you are using it all over the place, almost exclusively, why do you want to exclude it for *this* particular problem?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Are there really? I wouldn't know, they didn't tell us that when they taught us Ruby at university. In that case, I'd be happy to use the Numeric class. I just struggle to understand documentation and when I googled the problem, the documentation for the Numeric class seemed very confusing to me. Please note that I am only a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Going with your question's title:

```
str = "6'11\""

def to_inch(x)
  ( x.split("'")[0].to_i * 12 ) +
  x.split("'")[1].to_i
end

to_inch(str)
=> 83
```

If you want to complete the example you should also check the format of `str`.

**Edit**:
If you want to be inventive, here's a version without `to_i`:

```
h = {}
0.upto(12) { |x| h[x.to_s] = x }

def to_inch(x, ha)
  ( ha[x.split("'")[0]] * 12 ) +
  ha[x.split("'")[1].chomp("\"")]
end

to_inch(str, h)
=> 83
```

Comment: Note that you are using no less than 7 instances of the `Numeric` class in your code, whereas the OP seems to not want to use the `Numeric` class.

Comment: ... I assume that numbers can be used, only casts should to be avoided. It's possible to work around that completely but that would make it unnecessarily complicated imho.